# how to add string with special character in xslt

Tags: xslt, text, xslt-1.0, special-characters, addition

I want to add the following `<!DOCTYPE mlc_lts SYSTEM "mlc_lts.dtd">` in xsl, it contains special characters hence am not able to parse it.

it tried to add it text like this

```
<text><!DOCTYPE mlc_lts SYSTEM "mlc_lts.dtd"> </text>
```

it did not work. blow is my code:

```
<connection_param>
    <mlc_props_file>
        <file_full_path>./fs/public/mxres/mxmlc/mlc_properties.mxres</file_full_path>
    </mlc_props_file>
</connection_param>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you could do, is this....

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE mlc_lts SYSTEM "mlc_lts.dtd"&gt;</xsl:text>
```

Or maybe this...

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<!DOCTYPE mlc_lts SYSTEM "mlc_lts.dtd">]]></xsl:text>
```

However, you could also use the `doctype-system` attribute on `xsl:output` here

```
 <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-system="mlc_lts.dtd" />
```

For example, try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-system="mlc_lts.dtd" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, if you apply it to your XML in the question, you would get this generated

```
<!DOCTYPE connection_param SYSTEM "mlc_lts.dtd">
```

Where `connection_param` is the root element in your XML.

Comment: using this one 
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<!DOCTYPE mlc_lts SYSTEM "mlc_lts.dtd">]]></xsl:text>

 gave me
&lt;!DOCTYPE mlc_lts SYSTEM &quot;mlc_lts.dtd&quot;&gt;. I know that these are the represntation in HTML for greater than and quotation mark is (&quot;). i want it to be displayed as < and "

Comment: How are you performing the transformation. I think the issue is that "disabled-output-escaping" it not always supported.

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

 <xsl:template match="/">


  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
   <![CDATA[<!DOCTYPE mlc_lts SYSTEM "mlc_lts.dtd">]]></xsl:text>




 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet> @Tim C

Comment: Can you say what processor are you actually using to perform the transformation?

Answer (score -1):

Declare a variable and pass it's value to the node.

```
<xsl:variable name = "filepath" select = '"./fs/public/mxres/mxmlc/mlc_properties.mxres"'/> 

<connection_param>
    <mlc_props_file>
        <file_full_path><xsl:value-of select="$filepath"/></file_full_path>
    </mlc_props_file>
</connection_param>
```

Comment: Use &lt; and &gt; in place of the inequality symbols.